# Unable to run startx after installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, xorg

After installing the nvidia drivers as part of the CUDA install, Ubuntu 2020 would only boot to tty. Running startx doesnt work and fails with errors.

Comment: You may need to disable Secure Boot in UEFI.

Answer (score 1):

I found that hiding (or removing, but do that at your own risk) the xorg.conf and its variations (I had xorg.conf, xorg.conf.backup, xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original, and xorg.conf.orig.vgl) in /etc/X11 and re-installing the xserver with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg
```

Solved the issue for me.

Comment: That sounds strange, since Ubuntu starts with "wayland" not with the X11-server. Or did you change the settings in the login?